# Missing dependencies references for module

Tags: angular

I'm trying a small project with Angular and api-ai-javascript library.

The module is included with : `import { ApiAiClient} from 'api-ai-javascript';` as usual. But in this case I got an error for each typescript file from this module : `file xxx is missing from the TypeScript compilation`

In this case I'm doing the same thing for any other modules imported to my projects.

Any ideas ?

Comment: what is file name `xxx`?

Comment: At first the error is for node_modules\api-ai-javascript\index.ts . Then if include this file at the files section on tsconfig.app.json and tsconfig.spec.json, I got the some error for each one of the .ts files at node_modules\api-ai-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding `index.ts` of `api-ai-javascript` file to `tsconfig.json's` `include` block as:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
  },
  "include": [
    ...
    "node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Got the same error : ERROR in ./node_modules/api-ai-javascript/index.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\desenvfolder\Dialogflow\chat\node_modules\api-ai-javascript\index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

Comment: try adding them "../node_modules/api-ai-javascript/*.ts",   "../node_modules/api-ai-javascript/**/*.ts"

Comment: also add `"../node_modules/api-ai-javascript/ts/Request/TTSRequest.ts"` in excludes

Comment: The missing files error is fixed ( Thank you ! ) but now there's an strange situation when the view is exposed with no error at the console...I got only a blank screen with something like a loop at the presentation level

Comment: Hey @GCoe I'am not aware about this lib so if you are having any error in console may be I can help but can't with this module. Sorry :( For this you can accept & upvote this answer. :)